# OR Logical operation in Firestore Query

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to apply OR operation in firestore queries like:

if (name == "Jhon" || lastname == "James") {
  then do this
}

Comment: please show your current firebase querry

Comment: @PhanVanLinh I am using this query for now :

Comment: query.whereEqualTo("name", "Jhon").whereEqualTo("lastname", "James");

Comment: There isn't a direct way to do this, however, if you want to write complex queries, the recommended approach is to use Firestore.

Comment: @JoelFernandes i tried every way but they are all AND Logical operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Firebase Web SDK Version 9.18.0, `OR` queries are now supported.

v9.18.0 Release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#9.18.0

> Added support for disjunctions in OR queries. See Github PR #7053.

`OR queries` Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries

Comment: thanks the latest update of firebase has added the "OR" query option

Answer (score 6):

It currently seems that Firestore does not support disjunctions.

Workaround would be to merge results of queries `query.whereEqual(name, John)` and `query.whereEqual(surname, James)`.

Keep in mind, that from the result you have to delete the duplicated ones, those which are evaluated as true in both conditions.

Comment: the way you proposed is to get to list of objects from the same collection but filtering it differently and merge it together to get the workaround for OR Logical operation.

Comment: could you please give me an example of merging two queries together

Comment: @AnooshKhalid he mean that you have to get every result alone and then merging them manually in one list.