# How to use "OR" op for compositeFilter in Firestore REST API runQuery

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on [Firestore REST API runQuery](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/firestore/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.projects.databases.documents.runQuery)

I would like to get all documents which fulfill this criteria:

`college == 'CUHK' OR college == 'HKU'`

I was looking for `"OR"` in the op of composite filter, unfortunately it doesn't exist
[(Firestore Official Documentation)](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/StructuredQuery#Operator)

Is there any alternative for the query below? (something I want but doesn't exist)

```
{
 "structuredQuery": {
  "from": [
   {
    "collectionId": "participants"
   }
  ],
  "where": {
   "compositeFilter": {
    "op": "OR", // <- what I want
    "filters": [
     {
      "fieldFilter": {
       "field": {
        "fieldPath": "college"
       },
       "op": "EQUAL",
       "value": {
        "stringValue": "CUHK"
       }
      }
     }, // OR
     {
      "fieldFilter": {
       "field": {
        "fieldPath": "college"
       },
       "op": "EQUAL",
       "value": {
        "stringValue": "HKU"
       }
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: _"Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app."_ From [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did think of it but it is not optimised to perform orderBy and pagination operation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092740/or-logical-operation-in-firestore-query, and this issue on the Firestore JavaScript SDK repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/321